# VSCode doesn't delete older version of extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developer behind a more clean Monokai Theme on VScode. [It is more of a simple hack.]

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Mit.Monokai-Polished

Whenever I release a minor update VScode doesn't delete older version from `/extensions` folder after reloading the window. How do I remove this bug.

My source code is for extension is available at [this repo](https://github.com/foxtrot9/monokaiPolishedVSCode).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The older version will not be deleted if you just *reload* VSCode (clicking the `Reload` button in Extensions tab or using the `Reload Window` command. In order to really delete the older version, you need to *Restart* VSCode (close and reopen, all instances).

By the way, it appears to be designed this way, and not a bug. ([related issue in VSCode repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/537#issuecomment-169019370)).

Comment: I've tried multiple times closing and reopening VSCode but the extensions of the previous version do not delete. Is there any other solution? Please let me know!

Comment: Reloading/Restarting VS Code worked for me to delete older extensions.

Comment: Restarting VSCode parially helps. I updated VScode from 1.76.1 to 1.85.1 on an old Mac and initially the extensions folder took around 9 Gigabytes (with the old versions of my custom profiles, which I renamed and refactored in 2023 after profiles sync has been fixed).

After updating all the profiles' extensions (unfortunately, I need to open all the 20 profiles to ensure that extenstions are up to date), I restarted VScode and the extensions folder became of 5+ Gigabytes.

Comment: However, I found a number of extensions, mostly from 2020 (when the profile sync has been introduced) and some from 2021-22 up to 500 Megabytes. I switched between profiles with restart in some of my profiles with a bunch of extensions, but nothing helped. I ended up with sorting by date and moving these old extensions out of the extensions folder. After that I tested my profiles by switching to some of them and restaring VScode.

So, this solution is working for 80% to 85% of extensions :)

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VS Code fixes the issue sometimes, but not all the time.

Ended up writing a script to clean up old extensions consistently.

```
function global:VSCode_Delete_Extensions
{
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$FolderPath
    )

    # Get all subfolders in the specified directory
    $subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $FolderPath -Directory

    # Create a hashtable to store folder names and their respective paths
    $folderNameHash = @{}

    foreach ($folder in $subfolders) {

        $Shrink_Folder_Name_Length = [math]::Ceiling($folder.Name.Length * 0.10)
        $Shrink_Folder_Name_Length = $folder.Name.Length - $Shrink_Folder_Name_Length
        $key = $folder.Name.Substring(0, [Math]::Min($Shrink_Folder_Name_Length, $folder.Name.Length))

        if (-not $folderNameHash.ContainsKey($key)) {
            $folderNameHash[$key] = @($folder)
        }
        else {
            $folderNameHash[$key] += $folder
        }
    }

    # List to hold folders to be deleted
    $foldersToDelete = @()

    # Identify the folder with the oldest creation date for each key
    foreach ($key in $folderNameHash.Keys) {
        if ($folderNameHash[$key].Count -gt 1) {
            Write-output ""
            Write-Output "Similar folders for key '$key':"

            # Identify the folder with the oldest creation date
            $oldestFolder = $folderNameHash[$key] | Sort-Object CreationTime | Select-Object -First 1
            $foldersToDelete += $oldestFolder

            foreach ($folder in $folderNameHash[$key]) {
                $modifiedDate = $folder.LastWriteTime
                $createdDate = $folder.CreationTime
                Write-Output ("`t" + $folder.FullName + " (Modified: $modifiedDate, Created: $createdDate)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    write-host ""
    write-host ""
    write-host ""

    # Delete the folders in $foldersToDelete
    foreach ($folder in $foldersToDelete) {
        Write-Output "Deleting folder: $($folder.FullName)"
        #Remove-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Recurse -Force
        Remove-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Recurse -whatif
    }
}
```

Just call the function VSCode_Delete_Extensions and provide a folder path. Use the whatif to check what's gonna be deleted and then uncomment the line above to actually delete the extensions.